# Zend Framework application.xml modules loading

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I rewrote my config from .ini to .xml and I've got a 
problem with my modules. When my configs was stored in .ini
I wrote resources.modules[] = 
and zend loads all my modules and models of it when bootstrapping. 
How I can use it in .xml? 
Now I simple write

```
<resources>
  <modules></modules> 
</resources>
```

and it does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add placeholder. It works for me.

```
<resources>
    <modules>
        <!-- Placeholder to ensure an array is created -->
        <placeholder />
    </modules>
</resources>
```